# html2canvas, proxy to read facebook images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, html2canvas

I am trying to use the html2canvas to render a img from a div, which contains some images, and they could be or not from facebook servers, but I don't know how to use the proxy option for this purpose.
Here's my html code and js code:

```
<div class="layout show" id="layout_2">
  <div class="quadro two ui-droppable" data-id="105" style="background-image: url(http://www.fotoclub.com.br/css/capas/loading.gif);">
    <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/1395770_689674961065927_34713189_n.jpg" class="two">
  </div>
  <div class="quadro two ui-droppable" data-id="109" style="background-image: url(http://www.fotoclub.com.br/css/capas/loading.gif);">
    <img src="https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc1/1424485_689674991065924_420503222_n.jpg" class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
html2canvas($("#layout_2"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas_) {
        var canvas_div = document.getElementById("canvas_div");
        canvas_div.appendChild(canvas_);
    }
});
```

Then I have this div with the "canvas_div" ID down on page.

Comment: can you do a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I resolve my problem, with the this helpfull code at: https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-php-proxy